# AlarmManager no me hace caso y ejecuta el evento cuando quiere

Tags: android

Tengo un método que, con AlarmManager, el día 1 de cada mes debería ejecutar un código, pero lo ejecuta cada vez que abro la aplicación. Simplemente lo que hace es añadir una entrada a una base de datos. Tengo este método:

```
public void crack(Context context){
        // Establecemos el calendario.
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, ReceptorCrack.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: se ejecuta cada vez que abres la aplicación porque el día 1 ya pasó. No estas definiendo ni que mes ni que año

Comment: Pero necesito que se ejecute el día 1 de cada mes, da igual qué mes y año sea, pero el día 1 debe ejecutarse. De todas formas, el programa sigue haciendo lo que quiere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma sería obteniendo el primer día del siguiente mes:

```
// obtienes la fecha actual (hoy es 25/05/2018)
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int actualAnio = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);  // 2018
int actualMes = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);  // 05
// este es el día 1 del mes:
int primerDia = cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  

//así seteas esa fecha, en este caso queda 01/05/2018 08:30 am
cal.set(actualAño, actualMes, primerDia, 8,30,0);
// le agregas un mes 
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);
// por lo que quedaría así: 01/06/2018
// cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);  // si quieres que sea el día 5 ...
//lo puedes corroborar en el logCat:
Log.i("FECHA ", String.valueOf(cal.getTime()));
```

Al momento de estar ya en Junio, deberá cambiar a 01/07/2018 y así en cada mes.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando **[AlarmManager.RTC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC)**

> **[AlarmManager.RTC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC)**:  Esta alarma no activa el dispositivo; si se apaga mientras el
>   dispositivo está dormido, no se enviará hasta la próxima vez que el
>   dispositivo se despierte.

Por lo tanto, RTC entregará el `intent` solo cuando el dispositivo se active.

**Debes usar [AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP)
 si deseas que tu  servicio realice alguna operación  ya que  [AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP) activará el dispositivo y entregará el intento pendiente.**

Comment: Lo he cambiado pero sigue creando el evento al iniciar la aplicación.

Comment: Lo creara al iniciar la aplicación y posteriormente cada cierto tiempo que hayas definido en el Intent, te sugiero definas un tiempo más corto que cada día para probar.